# Where is rngd started? How to pass a parameter?

Tags: boot

The man page for rngd says there is an option -S to control the interval at which stats are written to sylog. I would like to change that interval but I can't find where rngd is started  at boot (which, I presume, is where I would add the -S option). This is on "bullseye". Can anyone help? My google-fu has failed me on this.

Thanks,

Sterling

Comment: What's in /etc/defaults for rngd? That's where you usually put startup parm overrides. Else edit the systemd rngd.service file and add the option in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Dougie, I edited the file /etc/default/rng-tools-debian and added a line `RNGDOPTIONS="-S 86400"` (to give me a 1 day interval) followed by a `sudo systemctl restart rng-tools.service` and that looks like it will do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

In general listing files which belong to a package usually helps finding its configs. If you have `rngd` installed, you can run `dpkg -L rng-tools-debian`, otherwise you can look at the package contents in the Debian [catalog](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/armhf/rng-tools-debian/filelist).